# Separate dotenv file into parts or use variables in dotenv file

Tags: environ

Now if I have .env file like

```
USE_DOCKER=yes
POSTGRES_DB=kbackend
USER=root
DB_URL=$USER:$POSTGRES_DB
```

when I use `env('DB_URL')` it returns to me `$USER:$POSTGRES_DB`
I want to return `root:kbackend`

- I use `django-environ`

Answer (score 0):

My original incorrect answer:

```
DB_URL=${USER}:${POSTGRES_DB}
```

Updated answer: Currently, `django-environ` does not support this. The relevant [code](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ/blob/628ed38e540ec9a6f3aff622953948e54f14a76d/environ/environ.py#L627):

```
logger.debug('Read environment variables from: {0}'.format(env_file))

for line in content.splitlines():
    m1 = re.match(r'\A([A-Za-z_0-9]+)=(.*)\Z', line)
    if m1:
        key, val = m1.group(1), m1.group(2)
        m2 = re.match(r"\A'(.*)'\Z", val)
        if m2:
            val = m2.group(1)
        m3 = re.match(r'\A"(.*)"\Z', val)
        if m3:
            val = re.sub(r'\\(.)', r'\1', m3.group(1))
        cls.ENVIRON.setdefault(key, str(val))
```

Comment: Not working and I tried `{{varr}}` but not working too

Comment: That code snippet is from`django-environ`. It does not attempt to use variables, it only processes the `.env` contents as strings. Thus what you're trying to do won't work.